# Docker Desktop(for Apple chip) not working on Apple M1 Max chip

Tags: docker, apple-m1

As I try to launch it, it stacks at starting state, and nothing happens. Reinstalling and installing prev. versions(4.4, 4.5) don't do the trick it is still stacking on starting...
After diagnose check:

```
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose check
```

and here are fails

```
[FAIL] DD0031: does the Docker API work? Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix://docker.raw.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
[FAIL] DD0004: is the Docker engine running? Get "http://ipc/docker": dial unix lifecycle-server.sock: connect: no such file or directory
[FAIL] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running? failed to ping VM diagnosticsd with error: Get "http://ipc/ping": dial unix diagnosticd.sock: connect: no such file or directory
[FAIL] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running? vm is not running: failed to open kmsg.log: open log/vm/kmsg.log: no such file or directory
[FAIL] DD0017: can a VM be started? vm has not started: failed to open kmsg.log: open log/vm/kmsg.log: no such file or directory
[FAIL] DD0003: is the Docker CLI working? exit status 1
[FAIL] DD0012: is the VM networking working? network checks failed: Post "http://ipc/check-network-connectivity": dial unix diagnosticd.sock: connect: no such file or directory
[FAIL] DD0032: do Docker networks overlap with host IPs? Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix://docker.raw.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

as a conclusion:

```
Please investigate the following 1 issue:

1 : The test: can a VM be started?
    Failed with: vm has not started: failed to open kmsg.log: open log/vm/kmsg.log: no such file or directory
```

Reset to a factory defaults seems not taking effect.
Rebooting also useless.

Comment: Have you downloaded the version for apple chip?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because of turned on VPN on network settings. Answer found [here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5304)